# Sort by date on React database call not working - just returning oldest first

Tags: reactjs

I have a Strapi CMS where I'm attempting to sort blog posts in order of the newest to oldest. I'm doing this through the 'published_at' attribute. I've done a bit of Googling this morning, and figured the most sensible solution would be to use 'sort()'.

However, it's not working, and I can't see why.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
  const posts = await strapiInstance.getEntries('blog-posts')
  const sortedPosts = posts.sort((a, b) => b.published_at - a.published_at)
  console.log(sortedPosts)
```

And the console log looks as follows:

```
0 Object

Author: "Jon Nicholson"

published_at: "2020-11-20T08:48:08.875Z"

updatedAt: "2020-12-06T10:59:31.723Z"

1 Object

Author: "Jon Nicholson"

published_at: "2020-11-26T08:51:52.414Z"

updatedAt: "2020-12-06T10:59:44.081Z"
```

I wondered if I needed to convert it into an integer perhaps before sorting?

But any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`published_at` is a String parameter, so if you use subtraction operation on them, it will return `NaN`. You can test this on console:

```
"2020-11-20T08:48:08.875Z" - "2020-11-26T08:51:52.414Z"
```

There are two other options: to compare by string

```
const sortedPosts = posts.sort((a, b) =>
  (b.published_at > a.published_at) 
    ? 1
    : (b.published_at === a.published_at ? 0 : -1)
)
```

or to compare after converting them to Date (if it's always return valid date string)

```
const sortedPosts = posts.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.published_at) - new Date(a.published_at))
```

Comment: Option 2 with converting into a Date is really clean and it's worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonNicholson if your backend can return `null` or empty value for `published_at` then you should be careful when using that solution. Thanks to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, just swap a & b in sort callback.

```
const posts = await strapiInstance.getEntries('blog-posts')
const sortedPosts = posts.sort((a, b) => a.published_at - b.published_at)
console.log(sortedPosts)
```